# Method which works on OSx and Linux to extract value between two strings?

Tags: macos, awk, sed, scripting, ksh

Given the strings below, how do I script extracting "12.0" using a method which works on Linux and OSX?  The sed example works on Linux, but not on OSX because the regex used isn't valid in OSX.  Is there a universal way to do this using awk perhaps?  Also looked into a variation using 'grep -oP', but that doesn't work on OSX either...  geez

#### Example string

```
Version=12.0;REG_SZ
Version=12.0; REG_SZ
Version=                       12.0;                       REG_SZ
```

#### Regex capture to get value between two strings using sed

```
sed -e 's/Version=\s\+\(.*\);.*REG_SZ/\1/g'
```

Comment: If **\s** doesn't seem to work for you, you can do it as **sed -e 's|^Version[ \t]*=[ \t]*\([^;]*\);.*$|\1|g'**. That uses space and a tab character in place of **\s**.

Comment: You could also use awk as **awk 'match($0,/^Version\s*=\s*([^;]*);.*$/,ary) {print ary[1]}'**

Comment: on OSX the number prints out as:  12.0;

Comment: "on OSX the number prints out as: 12.0;" ---> For sed or for awk?

Comment: awk, sorry...
running the last command you entered.

Comment: Could you run **awk -V** and show the output (or any other way to let us know what version of awk you are using)?

Comment: Could you try running gawk explicitly?

Comment: what is your expected output? `s/Version=\s\+\(.*\);.*REG_SZ/\1/g` will expect at least a space after `Version=` and hence will substitute only for 3rd line of your sample input... change `\s\+` to `\s*` to have zero or more spaces

Comment: if you have `perl` on both OSX and Linux, you can use `perl -pe 's/Version=\s*(.*);.*REG_SZ/$1/g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to a BSD/OSX box to test, but this should be portable:

```
sed 's/[^=]\+=[[:blank:]]*\([^;]\+\).*/\1/'
```

If you need to do this only on lines containing "REG_SZ", then

```
sed -n '/REG_SZ/s/[^=]\+=[[:blank:]]*\([^;]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: YMMV with `\+`. It won't work in all seds, idk about those specific 2.

Comment: The first example doesn't work on OSX.   That seems to be the case for most of the examples posted, not limited to this one...

Comment: I had a look at the [OSX `re_format(7)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format): it looks like you need `\{1,\}` instead of `\+` => `sed 's/[^=]\{1,\}=[[:blank:]]*\([^;]\{1,\}\).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

Since your sed and awk do not seem to handle **\s**, you could try to replace **\s** with a space and a tab character:

```
awk 'match($0,/^Version[ \t]*=[ \t]*([^;]*);.*$/,ary) {print ary[1]}'

sed -e 's|^Version[ \t]*=[ \t]*\([^;]*\);.*$|\1|g'
```

Also try explicitly using gawk (or nawk) if they are available.

Comment: The 3rd arg to match() is a gawk-specific extension.

Answer (score 0):

`\s` and `\+` are both non-portable. With any sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/Version=[ \t]*\([^;]*\).*/\1/p' file
12.0
12.0
12.0
```

Comment: for some reason OSX doesn't like '\t', as it appears to ignore it completely.   When run on Linux, the results are exactly as you showed above.  On OSX, there is a [TAB] character in front of each number.

Comment: then replace it with a literal tab character.